# Apache, htaccess, url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I have `.htaccess` file I'm using **for testing**, here is my file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{SERVER_NAME}/?title=%1 [L]
```

I'm using **Apache/2.4.10 (Win32)** from [ApacheLounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/)

I have the following domain and sub domain:

- example.com
- m.example.com

Both point to the same ip address, now as I expected from the above `.htaccess`:

if I access `example.com/Article-Name/` the redirection to `example.com/?title=Article-Name` will be **internal**, I won't be able to see `?title=Article-Name` on my url bar.

**Here is the exception:**

If I access `m.example.com/Article-Name/` the redirection to `m.example.com/?title=Article-Name` will be **external** and now I see `m.example.com/?title=Article-Name` in my url bar.

So I was expecting the same behavior, if anyone have an idea I will be very thankful.

**EDIT:**

I have found a solution for the problem but I still interesting about the above problem, about the solution is to use:

```
RewriteRule ^ ?title=%1 [L]
```

**Please notice:** this solution is only needed for **m.example.com**, I really have no idea how this solution is even working, I have posted this solution because it may help finding the cause for above problem, and how this solution is even working.

**EDIT 2(the full .htaccess file):**

```
RewriteEngine On


<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'avielfadida.ml'">

# The actual condition is really long one so I replaced it for illustration.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|Android) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://m.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# I have to duplicate the RewriteCond and RewriteRule both inside the <If> and <Else>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/?title=%1 [L]

# The solution(the solution is not required inside this block):
#RewriteRule ^ /?title=%1 [L]
</If>

<ElseIf "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'm.example.com'">

# I have to duplicate the RewriteCond and RewriteRule both inside the <If> and <Else>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/?title=%1 [L]

# The solution(the solution is required here):
# RewriteRule ^ /?title=%1 [L]

DirectoryIndex /m/index.htm /m/index.php /m/index.html
</ElseIf>
```

**Important note:** there is no relation between the full .htaccess file and the problem, the reason for this update is for the small chance I have made a mistake, anyway I have tested the .htaccess file with only the 3 lines from the question.

**[HERE IS THE HTTPD.CONF FILE](http://pastebin.com/H4Z0ifXT)**

**Last update:**

```
RewriteEngine On    

# The actual condition is really long one so I replaced it for illustration.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|Android) [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /?title=%1 [L]


<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'm.avielfadida.ml'">
    DirectoryIndex /m/index.htm /m/index.php /m/index.html
</If>
```

Comment: Do you have any other rule to redirect example.com to m.example.com when accessed from a mobile device? Also you may want to change `%{SERVER_NAME}` to `%{HTTP_HOST}`as `SERVER_NAME` takes the value as defined in the Apache config not based on the HTTP request header.

Comment: @VivekThomas Thanks for the comment, and about the directive, I'm using DirectoryIndex, but it doesn't relate, I have tested without the directive, I actually tested the above 3 lines, the problem is somehow in the subdomain, I really have no lead about the problem.

Comment: Try changing the 3rd line to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{SERVER_NAME}`.

Comment: @VivekThomas, I will give me a sec.

Comment: @VivekThomas, sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Are both hostnames under the same VirtualHost? Please update the question with the Apache config files.

Comment: @VivekThomas I will update the question and about the VirtualHost, I'm not using any, let me show you the full .htaccess file, just to state, even when the .htaccess file only contain the 3 lines from the question the problem is happen.

Comment: Ok, I see why giving the relative URL path works. From Apache docs

`If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a URL-path. Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given URL. To force an external redirect back to the current host, see the [R] flag below.`

Since m.example.com is considered as a different host, an external redirect is performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have done with the relative path is correct

```
RewriteRule ^ ?title=%1 [L]
```

From [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> Absolute URL
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to
>   see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the
>   scheme and hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated
>   as a URL-path. **Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the
>   given URL.** To force an external redirect back to the current host, see
>   the [R] flag below.

`m.example.com` would be considered as a different host and hence Apache performs an external redirect. So to make sure only an internal rewrite is performed, you need to use the relative path as you've done.

You could also strip down a lot of things from .htaccess file. I think this should do what you are looking for.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|Blackberry|Android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://m.exmaple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /?title=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this really good answer, I will also updated my .htaccess file I will post the change.